# Python: Remove intersecting line segments from graph until only the shortest of intersecting lines remains (remove dict from list of dicts)

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, planar-graph

[image]

Starting with the graph on the left, I would like to compare all of the lines, and anywhere they intersect (not counting the corners), keep only the shortest of the intersecting lines. I have the data on the lines stored as a list of dictionaries (in descending order of line length), but I can change the data structures however I want.

As as example from the graph above, inside the polygon 0 - 7 - 10 - 4, the line 0 - 10 is the shortest of all the intersecting lines, thus it remains and all others are deleted.

```
#this is a list of dictionaries of information on line segments
#every line is stored once, there are no duplicates. the lineKey is always "smaller node - bigger node"
#the z coordinates are for distance calculations only, and can be ignored when comparing intersection

aList = [
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 18530.79947007144,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "10 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 15094.74047474815,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 15087.677985694154,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 6",
        "systemDistance": 13941.484497714007,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 5",
        "systemDistance": 13795.211959227014,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 13656.901881466381,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 13624.975009151392,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 4",
        "systemDistance": 13103.056246540347,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 4",
        "systemDistance": 12588.223464810275,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 5",
        "systemDistance": 12163.407622866218,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 3",
        "systemDistance": 11672.869784247574,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 6",
        "systemDistance": 11603.377439349286,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 11461.436733673489,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 11339.625963849072,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 11131.267358212182,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 10897.890896866238,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 3",
        "systemDistance": 10878.028681705155,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "8 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 10854.954629108313,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 10174.693558038984,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 9463.07983692413,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 9334.584511374891,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 9238.597783213641,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "9 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 9189.37631180702,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 6",
        "systemDistance": 8592.218514446662,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 8314.787670169335,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 5",
        "systemDistance": 8160.395211017662,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 1",
        "systemDistance": 7432.292109437034,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 7376.253385018712,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 7339.821659958776,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 7132.109014870706,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 2",
        "systemDistance": 7033.502896850189,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 7020.516362775605,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "9 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 6688.316155804838,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 6652.693740132639,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 3",
        "systemDistance": 6647.047690516444,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 6401.402736900718,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 4",
        "systemDistance": 5789.121608672597,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 4",
        "systemDistance": 5568.060883287825,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "8 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 5546.51692506207,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 5315.179300832663,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 5143.00738867834,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 5140.250772092739,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 4797.691632441585,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 4745.356677848357,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 4677.538134531882,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 4607.626829507789,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 4521.789247631959,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 4520.097012233256,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 4465.506578205882,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 4299.277497440704,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 4267.25309771989,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "8 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 4238.518255239677,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 3858.9902824443598,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 3508.9494154233685,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 6",
        "systemDistance": 2209.7911666037585,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 2103.140984337474,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 6",
        "systemDistance": 1820.2340508846657,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 6",
        "systemDistance": 1756.2018676678374,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 1743.1133067015467,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 1674.4649891831123,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 1614.4252847375749,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 5",
        "systemDistance": 1289.1241212544276,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 2",
        "systemDistance": 921.2475237415838,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 5",
        "systemDistance": 770.2713807483698,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 445.4435991233907,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 284.6418802636042,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
]
```

```
#expected output
[
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 15087.677985694154,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 9238.597783213641,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 1",
        "systemDistance": 7432.292109437034,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 7020.516362775605,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 6652.693740132639,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 6401.402736900718,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 4",
        "systemDistance": 5789.121608672597,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 4",
        "systemDistance": 5568.060883287825,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 11",
        "systemDistance": 5315.179300832663,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 1165, "y": 1111, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 5140.250772092739,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 4745.356677848357,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 4607.626829507789,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "0 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 4520.097012233256,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 7051, "y": 13399, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 4465.506578205882,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 4299.277497440704,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "4 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 4267.25309771989,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5803, "y": 19052, "z": -5},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 7",
        "systemDistance": 3858.9902824443598,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 3508.9494154233685,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 6",
        "systemDistance": 1756.2018676678374,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "5 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 1743.1133067015467,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "3 - 10",
        "systemDistance": 1674.4649891831123,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 1022, "y": 16198, "z": 0},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 2695, "y": 16128, "z": -2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 1614.4252847375749,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "2 - 5",
        "systemDistance": 1289.1241212544276,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 2",
        "systemDistance": 921.2475237415838,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 5878, "y": 6464, "z": -4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "1 - 5",
        "systemDistance": 770.2713807483698,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 6660, "y": 5977, "z": -2},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 6359, "y": 5268, "z": 4},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "7 - 9",
        "systemDistance": 445.4435991233907,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4079, "y": 9878, "z": -1},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4479, "y": 9682, "z": -3},
    },
    {
        "lineKey": "6 - 8",
        "systemDistance": 284.6418802636042,
        "system1Coor": {"x": 4606, "y": 5162, "z": 4},
        "system2Coor": {"x": 4625, "y": 5446, "z": 2},
    },
]
```

```
#this is a function that determines if two of the line segments intersect
def lineIntersection(self, line1, line2):
    x1,y1,z1 = line1['system1Coor'].values()
    x2,y2,z2 = line1['system2Coor'].values()
    x3,y3,z3 = line2['system1Coor'].values()
    x4,y4,z4 = line2['system2Coor'].values()
    denom = (y4-y3)*(x2-x1) - (x4-x3)*(y2-y1)
    if denom == 0: # parallel
        return False
    ua = ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3) - (y4-y3)*(x1-x3)) / denom
    if (ua < 0 or ua > 1): # out of range
        return False
    ub = ((x2-x1)*(y1-y3) - (y2-y1)*(x1-x3)) / denom
    if (ub < 0 or ub > 1): # out of range
        return False
    
    return True

#this is a loop to compare all combinations of lines in the list and remove the longest line
#loop through once
for lineKey1 in aList:
    #loop through again
    for lineKey2 in aList:
        
        #check that the loop is not comparing the line to itself
        if lineKey1 != lineKey2:
            
            #check the loop is not comparing two lines that intersect at their corners
            if len(list(set(lineKey1['lineKey'].split(' - ')) & set(lineKey2['lineKey'].split(' - ')))) == 0:
            
                #check if the lines intersect
                if lineIntersection(lineKey1, lineKey2):
                
                    #get the larger of the two lines
                    maxSystemDistance = max(lineKey1['systemDistance'], lineKey2['systemDistance'])
                    
                    #get the value to remove from the list
                    if maxSystemDistance == lineKey1['systemDistance']:
                        lineValueToRemove = lineKey1
                    
                    #get the value to remove from the list
                    elif maxSystemDistance == lineKey2['systemDistance']:
                        lineValueToRemove = lineKey2
                    
                    #check if the value is in the list and remove it
                    if lineValueToRemove in aList:
                        aList.remove(lineValueToRemove)
```

The loop I have above removes most of the intersecting lines, but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the lines in order of length.
2. For each line:

   a. Check if the line intersects with any shorter lines (note: it will never
   intersect with any adjacent lines).

   b. If it does, remove it.
3. Repeat #2 for the next longest line.

*Note: your intersection algorithm will return that lines intersect if they touch at  the end-points; you do not want this and need to change the final test with `ua` and `ub` to not match intersections when they equal `0` or `1`.*

```python
from math import sqrt

class coord:
    def __init__(self,index,x,y,z):
        self.index = index
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class line:
    def __init__(self, coord1, coord2):
        self.coord1 = coord1
        self.coord2 = coord2
    
    def length(self):
        dx = self.coord1.x - self.coord2.x
        dy = self.coord1.y - self.coord2.y
        return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    
    def intersects(self, line):
        x1, y1 = self.coord1.x, self.coord1.y
        x2, y2 = self.coord2.x, self.coord2.y
        x3, y3 = line.coord1.x, line.coord1.y
        x4, y4 = line.coord2.x, line.coord2.y

        denom = (y4-y3)*(x2-x1) - (x4-x3)*(y2-y1)
        if denom == 0: # parallel
            return False
        ua = ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3) - (y4-y3)*(x1-x3)) / denom
        ub = ((x2-x1)*(y1-y3) - (y2-y1)*(x1-x3)) / denom
        return 0 < ua < 1 and 0 < ub < 1
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.coord1.index} - {self.coord2.index}"
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__();

coords = [
    coord( 0,  7051, 13399, -1),
    coord( 1,  6660,  5977, -2),
    coord( 2,  5878,  6464, -4),
    coord( 3,  1022, 16198,  0),
    coord( 4,  5803, 19052, -5),
    coord( 5,  6359,  5268,  4),
    coord( 6,  4606,  5162,  4),
    coord( 7,  4079,  9878, -1),
    coord( 8,  4625,  5446,  2),
    coord( 9,  4479,  9682, -3),
    coord(10,  2695, 16128, -2),
    coord(11,  1165,  1111, -3),
]

lines = [
    line(coords[ 4], coords[11]),
    line(coords[10], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 4], coords[ 6]),
    line(coords[ 4], coords[ 5]),
    line(coords[ 4], coords[ 8]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 4]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[ 4]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[ 5]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 3]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[ 6]),
    line(coords[ 5], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[ 8]),
    line(coords[ 6], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[ 3]),
    line(coords[ 8], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 4], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 4], coords[ 7]),
    line(coords[ 7], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 9], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 6]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 8]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 5]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 1]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 2]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[ 7]),
    line(coords[ 9], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 5], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 3]),
    line(coords[ 7], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 4]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[ 4]),
    line(coords[ 8], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 6], coords[11]),
    line(coords[ 5], coords[ 7]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 5], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 6], coords[ 7]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 7]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 7]),
    line(coords[ 6], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 0], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 7], coords[ 8]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 4], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 8], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[ 7]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 6]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 8]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[ 6]),
    line(coords[ 5], coords[ 6]),
    line(coords[ 5], coords[ 8]),
    line(coords[ 3], coords[10]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[ 8]),
    line(coords[ 2], coords[ 5]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 2]),
    line(coords[ 1], coords[ 5]),
    line(coords[ 7], coords[ 9]),
    line(coords[ 6], coords[ 8]),
]
    
sortedLines = sorted(
    lines,
    key=lambda line: line.length()
)

filteredLines = [
    line
    for index, line
    in enumerate(sortedLines)
    if not any(map(lambda l:line.intersects(l), sortedLines[:index]))
]

print(filteredLines)
```

Outputs:

> ```
> [6 - 8, 7 - 9, 1 - 5, 1 - 2, 2 - 5, 2 - 8, 3 - 10, 5 - 8, 5 - 6, 2 - 9, 2 - 7, 4 - 10, 1 - 9, 7 - 8, 0 - 9, 0 - 7, 6 - 7, 0 - 10, 6 - 11, 3 - 4, 0 - 4, 7 - 10, 5 - 11, 3 - 7, 0 - 1, 7 - 11, 3 - 11]
> ```

---

Or, for your input (rather than de-duplicating the information into classes):

```python
def lineIntersection(line1, line2):
    x1,y1,z1 = line1['system1Coor'].values()
    x2,y2,z2 = line1['system2Coor'].values()
    x3,y3,z3 = line2['system1Coor'].values()
    x4,y4,z4 = line2['system2Coor'].values()
    denom = (y4-y3)*(x2-x1) - (x4-x3)*(y2-y1)
    if denom == 0: # parallel
        return False
    ua = ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3) - (y4-y3)*(x1-x3)) / denom
    if (ua <= 0 or ua >= 1): # out of range
        return False
    ub = ((x2-x1)*(y1-y3) - (y2-y1)*(x1-x3)) / denom
    if (ub <= 0 or ub >= 1): # out of range
        return False
    
    return True

sortedLines = sorted(
    aList,
    key=lambda line: line['systemDistance']
)

filteredLines = [
    line
    for index, line
    in enumerate(sortedLines)
    if not any(map(lambda l:lineIntersection(line, l), sortedLines[:index]))
]

print(filteredLines)
```